# How to access Vmware Esxi Server from Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, vmware-server

I want to take control of my VMware ESXi 5  Server through Ubuntu 12.04.1 desktop. Unfortunately there is no client available for Ubuntu. How can I do it?

Comment: You can take basic control of a VMware ESXi server through VMWare Workstation, but that's costly, and designed to provide what Virtualbox provides.  Ultimately, you'll need to use Windows with a VSphere Client software install on it to make it work

Answer (score 2):

The vSphere Client is only available for Windows systems and it is not available for Linux systems.

The solution is to use vSphere Web Client.

More info in the [VMware Knowledge Database](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006095).

Comment: vSphere Web Client is also available only for Windows not linux visit this http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/documentLinkInt.do?micrositeID=&popup=true&languageId=&externalID=2005083.

Comment: I have successfully used the web client for some basic stuff like template management and vm settings modifications. I don't know what is not compatible but anyways I always access my vms through ssh or rdp so the way the web client works on linux is plenty for me.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and our resolution was to run a Windows VM on our Ubuntu machines purely just to be able to run the VSphere Client

VMware player is a free download. Something to note, it is quite resource intensive and requires at least 4 GB of RAM to run smoothly on Ubuntu.

[Link to download VMWare player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to mention this project: **[vEMan](https://sourceforge.net/projects/veman/)**, which looks like an unofficial ESXi manager. I didn't try it, but perhaps you'll have some luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

We can manage VM Ware ESXI through VM Ware workstation. Install VM Ware workstation on your Ubuntu pc and you can connect ESXI Host with the same workstation. Preferring Workstation 12 or higher versions.